# mvc: How do I add a initial Item to a DropDownList with Key of 0 and Description of 'Show All'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is an extract of my FormViewModel :

```
    public SummaryFormViewModel(IEnumerable<Site> sites, IEnumerable<Landowner> landowners)
    {

        var sitesValues = sites
            .OrderBy(s => s.SiteDescription)
            .Select(s => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(s.SiteId, s.SiteDescription));
        this.Sites = new SelectList(sitesValues, "Key", "Value");
```

I'd like to insert (as the first item) a value that will automatically be the default. It is to have a key of 0 and a description of 'Show All'

Basically i'm offering combo boxes to the user to allow them to filter results.

I'm needing a neat way to add this initial row to the SelectList

Can anyone Advise me please, thanks in Advance

J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the overloads of the HTML.Dropdown method accepts a label for the first item. Something like:

```
Html.Dropdown("MyDropdown", Model.Sites, "Show All")
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492883.aspx

Comment: If that defaults to value="" then that would probable be ideal.  Use `int?` and check `.HasValue`.  Much more efficient and clear if it works out.

Comment: Yes, it's value is empty string

Comment: Of course, thanks for the help, does anyone know how to mark Questions as answered? Cannot see any options on the page.

Comment: @John: click the tick outline beside the relevant answer, it will go green and the question will be marked as answered.

Answer (score 2):

You can use .ToList() then .Insert() to add in a new value.

Example:

```
    var sitesValues = sites
        .OrderBy(s => s.SiteDescription)
        .Select(s => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(s.SiteId, s.SiteDescription))
        .ToList();
    sitesValues.Insert(0, new KeyValuePair<int, string>(0, "Show All"));

    this.Sites = new SelectList(sitesValues, "Key", "Value");
```